# How to count the appearances of certain string/words on each row in a column in a dataframe using python

Tags: python, dataframe

How to count the appearances of certain string/words on each row in a column in a dataframe?

for example:

```
column
=================================================
I am not hungry
He does not angry
I believe him
I can not believe that he does not believe me
```

then i want to get the total of word "not" appeared in each row. What i want to get is:

```
column                                           |count word "not"
=================================================|================
I am not hungry                                  | 1
He does not angry                                | 1
I believe him                                    | 0
I can not believe that he does not believe me    | 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your code snippet ,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = {
    'Column':['I am not hungry','He does not angry','I believe him','I can not believe 
         that he does not believe me'],'Count':['0','0','0','0']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1,columns=['Column','Count'])
for ind in df1.index:
    df1['Count'][ind] = df1['Column'][ind].count('not')
print(df1)
```

and here is the output

```
                                          Column Count
0                                I am not hungry     1
1                              He does not angry     1
2                                  I believe him     0
3  I can not believe that he does not believe me     2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one liner code if you like -

```
df['count word "not"'] = df['column'].apply(lambda x : len([c for c in x.split(' ') if c == 'not']))
```